# Operators and Expressions Problem that I can not solve in C#

Tags: c#, operators, expression

We are given the number n, the value v (v = 0 or 1) and the position p. write a sequence of operations that changes the value of n, so the bit on the position p has the value of v. Example: n=35, p=5, v=0 -> n=3. Another example: n=35, p=2, v=1 -> n=39.

I am unable to find a way to only use that bit on the position p.

If i do n >> p with a number such as 35 in bits I will have
100011 >> 5 = 00001

I don't know how to get the value of v here. 
Mathematically even if I think about it above the value of n becomes 1 not 3 after this operation. I am totally confused as I can not explain the problem to myself.

```
  Console.Write("Enter n: ");
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter p: ");
    int p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter v: ");
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int mask = n >> 5;
    Console.WriteLine(mask);
```

Comment: The variable name `mask` imply you are learning about masking. Find a tutorial explaining what is *bit masking*. To set bit - use `or` with the mask. To clear - `xor` with inverted mask. Where mask is created by shifting `1 << position`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take this approach:

- Work out the shifted value of the bit using the `<<` operator
- If `v` is 1, set the bit using `|`
- Otherwise, clear it using `&` (and `~` for bitwise negation to create a mask)

So something like:

```
int shifted = 1 << p;

if (v == 1)
{
    n |= shifted; // Set the bit 
}
else
{
    // Clear the bit, by masking with the bitwise inverse  of the shifted value
    n &= ~shifted;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the swift response.
This seem to have worked!

Comment: @grozdeto: Do you understand each part of it though? Just having the code isn't terribly useful. Do let me know if there's anything you want me to clarify.

Comment: Hi, JonSkeet - this is totally off-topic but I give it a try anyway your article http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx is the #1 on Google when searching this topic if you want and have time would be great if you could update the topic with the new possibility of `C#` to init a member `public static SingleTon Instance { get; } = new SingleTon();`

Comment: @RandRandom: That's basically just version 4.

Comment: Yes I understood it. Thank you for checking on me @JonSkeet. I read about masking and I understood the principle of turning off and on certain bits. Thank you!